# Как найти скрипт который отправляет запросы

Tags: linux

в системе есть скрипт который оправляет запросы по UDP. Каким образом его можно найти(отследить)? В процессах ничего необычного не нашел, в netstat порт 1047 с которого идут запросы ничего не показал.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/192893/292034

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

Это приложение, которое «знает» структуру самых различных сетевых протоколов, и поэтому позволяет разобрать сетевой пакет, отображая значение каждого поля протокола любого уровня.